# Get multiple values from one HTML input through Python Flask

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I have a dynamically generated number of rows containing text boxes in a table with a default value (order_quantity). Basically on a post I want my items table in sql to be updated with the values of these text boxes according to their ID's.

```
{% for i in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"  value="{{ i.order_quantity }}">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
             ...
             </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

There's no problem passing in the order_quantity OR the item ID but not both obviously.

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"  value="{{i.item_id}} {{ i.order_quantity }}">
```

Python:

```
amount = request.form.getlist('amount')
print amount
for i in amount:
    print i
```

In summary, how can I pass both the quantity and its relative id out in a simplistic manner for easy server-side extraction for each text box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by adding a hidden input field that holds the item_id

Example:

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"  value="{{ i.order_quantity }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ i.item_id }}"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

When you receive the input in Flask, you can match the id's to the amounts since the order is preserved.

```
amounts = request.form.getlist('amount')
item_ids = request.form.getlist('item_id')
for item_id, idx in enumerate(item_id):
    amount = amounts[idx]
    # do something with item_id and amount
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few hacky ways you can do this, you could for example comma delimit the ID and amount in the value eg,

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"  value="{{ i.order_quantity }}_{{ i.item_id }}">
```

and then split it on the server side with some logic.

```
for item in request.args:
    quantity, item_id = item.split('_')
```

But the above assumes you're not going to be editing the amount in the form. Which will probably be useless in most scenarios.  So let's look at a more editable solution...

I'd personally do it this way, by putting the item ID in the name

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount-{{ i.item_id }}"  value="{{ i.order_quantity }}">
```

And then use the logic

```
for key, amount in request.args.items():
    item_id = key.split('-')[1]
    # And the amount var has the amount.
```

Answer (score 0):

An adapted solution of junnytony's worked for me-

```
amounts = request.form.getlist('amount')
item_ids = request.form.getlist('item_id')
for idx, am in zip(item_ids, amounts):

    print idx, am
```

Using the hidden input field (item_id) as suggested above.